# Animation in UICollectionViewCell Stops When Reloading Array Data

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit, core-animation

When using a **`UICollectionViewCell`** with animation triggered by a gesture recognizer, the animation stops abruptly when the array data associated with the collection view is reloaded using **`reloadData()`** method. The UICollectionViewCell contains a UILabel with an animation that scales the cell upon a long-press gesture. However, when **`reloadData()`** is called to update the data in the collection view, the animation of the UICollectionViewCell resets to its initial state, causing it to stop abruptly. This behavior disrupts the user experience and prevents the animation from completing smoothly as intended. The challenge is to find a solution that allows the animation to continue seamlessly even after the data is reloaded, ensuring a smooth and uninterrupted user interaction.

*Horizontal Cell of UICollectionView:*

```
final class HorizontalCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let reuseIdentifier = "HorizontalCollectionViewCell"
    
    private let numberLabel = UILabel()
    private var originalTransform: CGAffineTransform?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
        setupGestureRecognizers()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        numberLabel.text = nil
    }
    
    private func setupViews() {
        contentView.addSubview(numberLabel)
        numberLabel.textAlignment = .center
        numberLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        numberLabel.layer.borderWidth = 3
        numberLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        numberLabel.backgroundColor = .white
        numberLabel.textColor = .black
        numberLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
        configure(with: item)
        
        numberLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
        }
    }
    
    var item: Int! = 0 {
        didSet {
            configure(with: item)
        }
    }
    
    private func configure(with number: Int) {
        numberLabel.text = "\(number)"
    }
    
    private func setupGestureRecognizers() {
        let tapGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        tapGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
        tapGesture.delegate = self
        addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
    
    @objc private func handleTap(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
                let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
                animation.duration = 0.1
                animation.fromValue = 1.0
                animation.toValue = 0.8
                animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
                animation.fillMode = .forwards
                
                CATransaction.begin()
                CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
                    self.transform = self.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.8, y: 0.8)
                }
                
                self.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
                CATransaction.commit()
            }
        case .ended, .cancelled:
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
                let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
                animation.duration = 0.1
                animation.fromValue = 0.8
                animation.toValue = 1.0
                animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
                animation.fillMode = .forwards
                
                CATransaction.begin()
                CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
                    self.transform = self.originalTransform ?? .identity
                }
                
                self.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
                CATransaction.commit()
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }

}

extension HorizontalCell: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        true
    }
}
```

*Timer starting method from Update Service class:*

```
private func startTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateRandomNumber), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        let runloop = RunLoop.main
        runloop.add(timer!, forMode: .common)
    }
    
    @objc private func updateRandomNumber() {
        for index in 0..<verticalItems.count {
            var updatedHorizontalItems = verticalItems[index].horizontalItems
            if let randomIndex = updatedHorizontalItems.indices.randomElement() {
                updatedHorizontalItems[randomIndex] = Int.random(in: 1...100)
            }
            verticalItems[index].horizontalItems = updatedHorizontalItems
        }
    }
```

HorizontalCell is stored into UITableViewCell, which sets a new item for HorizontalCell and reloads a UICollectionView in didSet { }. UITableView reloads in UIViewController method when gets any changes from array in UpdateService.

Comment: When you call `reloadData` then all cells are reloaded. You are no going to be able to keep the animation running if you reload the collection view. Your only option is to try inserting new items/sections as needed instead of using `reloadData`.

Comment: Thank you, but it also stops an animation

Comment: Core animation applies animations to the CALayers that back the views you are animating. If you replace those views, the animations are lost. In order to keep the animation(s) running you would need to keep your views that are being animated in the view hierarchy. reloadData would **certainly** kill your animation. HangarRash's suggestion of inserting items seems like it should work, but you would need to see if the views you are animating are left in the view hierarchy after the insertion.